# Firebase doesnt work properly on android, even though we can see traffic?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

Firebase only works on unity editor, not when we actually build it to android, it gets stuck at waiting for login with email and password functions. Although, it seems to working to some extent as we can see traffic on the firebase website. Thus we tried using simpler code instead, which is what someone else suggested, but it still doesnt come past the async code, is there any solution im missing, maybe something in the player settings is preventing it from working.

```
//Heres the current code, the texts are just flags, and it gets to "sigma" and never loads next scene:

using Firebase.Extensions;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Database;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Permissions : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text t;
    string[] temp = { Permission.ExternalStorageRead, Permission.ExternalStorageWrite };

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Permission.RequestUserPermissions(temp);
        t.text = "ligma";

        CheckIfReady();
    }
    public void CheckIfReady()
    {
        t.text = "sigma";
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            t.text = "figma";
            
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                Firebase.FirebaseApp app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Auth");
               // Debug.Log("Firebase is ready for use.");
            }
            else
            {
                t.text = "else";
            }
        });


    }
}
```

We tried using the prementioned code, because we thought it was a dependencie problem, however even that failed, so now we dont really know what to do. Maybe something in the player settings. I also tried asking chatGPT for some answers, and it suggested runtime scripts of .NET 4.x, which i didnt manage to find. I only found backend scripts, which were only .NET 2.1 and .NET framework. I dont really know if that is a problem, but im unsure.

Again were only experiencing errors, when actually building the game, the editor runs fine however.

Answer (score 0):

We removed the firebase folder in our project, then we reimported it and now it seems work fine. Thanks for all the help guys, your comments were really helpful and i wish to see you another time! Best regards from me!